# sublime text 3 C compiler (how can i use functions with header file in main.c)

Tags: c, function, sublimetext3

I want to compile multiple files together located in the same folder 
(main.c function.c function.h)
where function.h is included in main.c like #include "function.h"
-in codeblocks it works fine
-in sublime text 3 there is a problem that it compiles files individually and pops errors.
can anyone help !

[image]

Comment: Do some research about *makefiles*. And remember that Sublime Text 3 is just a *text editor*. It have some limited support to execute external programs, but it have none for actually building programs.

Comment: Post text content as _text_, not a _picture or text_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Undefined reference* is a linker error, not a compiler error.  You may have compiled all the necessary modules, but you then need to execute the linker to link those modules and any library code and run-time start-up.  It looks you are compiling and linking main.o on its own.

The Code::Blocks IDE will have performed complete the link by virtue of all your modules being part of your project because it is an *IDE* - it integrates an editor, compiler, linker and debugger.  Sublime Text is *only* a text editor, you have to tell it exactly what command is required to build your code.  For a multi-module build, you may want to consider using a makefile or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am already using a build system for compiling c codes but it seems that it works for individual files not multiple files at same time >> do you know a build system for compiling multiple files at the same time as in functions and header files??

```json
{
  "cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-std=c11" , "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
  "selector": "source.c",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "shell": true
}
```